# What capacitor is this (part number)? Looking for the datasheet

Tags: capacitor, components, datasheet

[image: Top of the capacitor]
[image: Bottom of the capacitor]

I'm trying to find the datasheet for this 1.0F & 5.5V capacitor. Some identifying labels on it are "GC", "Japan", and "822". I haven't had luck in my googling, so does anyone know what part number this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems consistent with Panasonic's discontinued stacked coin type of double layer capacitor. They refer to them as a "**G**old **C**apacitor" which might explain the "GC" labeling. The country of origin for Panasonic electrolytic capacitors is Japan. Multiple part numbers match the 5.5V and 1F parameters. However, other manufacturers such as Nichicon or Rubycon might also match all of these criteria. (I don't know if they also use "gold capacitor" terminology; it seems to only be associated with Panasonic.)

Some similar part numbers but with leads attached are:

- [EECS5R5_105](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDG0000/ABC0000C86.pdf)
- [EECS5R5_105N](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDG0000/ABC0000C87.pdf)

Where the underscore is replaced by V or H depending on terminal style.

A possible better match might be [EEC-F5R5H105N](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Capacitors%20PDFs/EEC-F5R5_Series_Rev_Mar_2018.pdf) based on what I presume are radial leads on the side of the cap you didn't photograph.

In any case, without more information it's difficult to tell which series it is, what its temperature rating is, etc.

Comment: I included the bottom of the capacitor in a new picture; yes, they are radial leads. The last link you included definitely looks more-so like what I have.